# How to use different colorpalette for each subplot in seaborn catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am plotting categorical data with seaborn catplot.
I want to make 2 plots from my data, they just differ in that the x, hue and col parameters are swapped around.

[image]
[image]

In the second plot, every bar in subplot "C" would be shades of green to correspond with the legend coloring from the first plot.
"D" would be red, "E" purple, etc.

How can I do that? I want to use some method where I can still let Seaborn calculate the error bars.

The code for the plots is

```py
    fig:sns.FacetGrid = sns.catplot(kind="bar", data = data, 
                    y="Value", x="config", hue="Surface", col="Height", col_wrap=2)
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    fig:sns.FacetGrid = sns.catplot(kind="bar", data = data[data["Surface"] != "A"], 
                    y="Value", x="Height", hue="Config", col="Surface", col_wrap=2)
    for ax,title in zip(fig.axes, ["C", "D", "E", "B"]):
        ax.set_title(title)
    fig.set_all_xlabels("Height")
    fig.set_xticklabels([2.8, 7.8, 12.8, 22.8])
    fig._legend.set_title("Config")
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.74)
```

I gave it a shot but this still isn't working correctly:

```py
    g: sns.FacetGrid = sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="Config", col="Surface", 
        hue_order=[1,2,3], col_order=["C", "D", "E", "B"], col_wrap=2,
        **figure_kwargs, **kwargs)
    
    def draw_colored_subplots(*args, **kwargs):
        color_order = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
        color_palette = sns.color_palette("muted")
        values = color_palette.as_hex()
        d = kwargs["data"]
        base_color = values[color_order.index(d["Surface"].iloc[0])]
        sns.barplot(*args, **kwargs, **error_kwargs, palette=sns.light_palette(base_color))

    g.map_dataframe(draw_colored_subplots, y="Value", x="Height")
```

Gives me the error

```
Passing `palette` without assigning `hue` is deprecated and will be removed in v0.14.0. Assign the `x` variable to `hue` and set `legend=False` for the same effect.
UserWarning: The palette list has more values (6) than needed (4), which may not be intended.
  sns.barplot(*args, **kwargs, **error_kwargs, palette=sns.light_palette(base_color))
```

and no legend is created. Somehow this is not passed through from the facetgrid?
If I pass `hue` explicitly to `sns.barplot` I get the error

```
seaborn.utils._get_patch_legend_artist.<locals>.legend_artist() got multiple values for keyword argument 'label'
```

But the image produced is not that bad, the coloring is getting there, even though the hue should not be the same as the x axis. And the bars overlap and the legend is missing.

[image: My own try]

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working. But if this isn't a hackjob idk what is.
If anyone has improvements please let me know!
[image]

```py
    data = get_data() # global data variable
    # create facetgrid
    g: sns.FacetGrid = sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="magn_angle", col="Lamella_Type", 
        hue_order=['1','2','3'], col_order=["C", "D", "E", "B"], 
        col_wrap=2, legend_out=True)
    
    def draw_colored_subplots(*args, **kwargs):
        color_order = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
        color_palette = sns.color_palette("muted") # my selected color palette
        values = color_palette.as_hex()
        # get color of current surface type from color palette (also remove data from kwargs)
        cur_surf = kwargs.pop("data")["Lamella_Type"].iloc[0]
        base_color = values[color_order.index(cur_surf)]
        # create new color palette from the basecolor (fading to white),
        # 4 colors so that last bar is not nearly invisible, causes userwarning
        palette = sns.light_palette(base_color, reverse=True, n_colors=4), 
        # filter surface from global data, data passed from facet grid is not correctly filtered. Why isn't this done by the facet grid??
        data_p = data[data["Surface"]==cur_surf]
        # remove any incompatible kwargs before passing to barplot
        kwargs.pop("legend",None)
        kwargs.pop("hue", None)
        # plotting, passing hue again, bc this isnt done by the facet grid?, disabling legend
        sns.barplot(data_p, *args, **kwargs, **error_kwargs, palette=palette, hue="Config", hue_order=["1", "2", "3"], legend=False)

    g.map_dataframe(draw_colored_subplots, x="Height", y="Value")

    # custom legend, since all plots have different colors only use greyscale patches
    g.add_legend({"1":Patch(facecolor='gray'),
                  "2":Patch(facecolor='darkgray'),
                  "3":Patch(facecolor='lightgray')},
                  "Config", adjust_subtitles=True,
                  bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5), loc="right", frameon=False)
    for ax,title in zip(g.axes, ["C", "D", "E", "B"]):
        ax.set_title(title)
    g.set(ylim=ylim)
    g.set_all_xlabels("Value")
    g.set_xticklabels([2.8, 7.8, 12.8, 22.8])
    g.set_all_ylabels(y_title)
```